# Thread.CurrentCulture refers to client or server

Tags: .net, currentculture

Where does Thread.CurrentCulture gets it's data from? Client (browser) or server.

And another question, is this the right way to find out the culture of the user?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thread.CurrentCulture gets the info for the executing thread. ASP.NET code is running on the server; hence, this will give you the current culture of the server thread.

To find the client accepted languages, use [`HttpRequest.UserLanguages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userlanguages.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean in an ASP.NET environment? Normally the server culture is returned.

Maybe you can use this article on Auto-Culture Handling in ASP.NET (depending on browser languages):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163849.aspx